# KnockoutJS, Binding View

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm struggling with issues from KnockoutJS, I have block code below

```
var viewModel = function (value){
    this.name = ko.observable(value);
}
var model = {}; model.firstName = "ABC";
var AppViewModel = new viewModel(model.firstName);
ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel);
```

And in HTML i have a view with binding

```
data-bind="textInput: name".
```

It's good work. TextView display with text: "ABC".
I have a question. when I change value in TextView. Whether if that model (special firstName) update new value from textView ?

Comment: Your `model.firstName` variable is used only for the initialisation. It will not change with the input, only `viewModel.name` will be updated

Comment: This meaning, KnockoutJS binding one direction ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `model.firstName` is an `object property` but it isn't an `observable`, instead you're using that `object property` to set the `observable`, the `observable` is the two way binding, if you want `firstName` to be an observable/two way binding you can do it like so:

```
var viewModel = function (){
    VM = this;
    VM.firstName = ko.observable("ABC");
    return VM;
}

var AppViewModel = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel);
```

Here we're creating a function `viewModel()` that returns an `object` with the property `firstName` which is a knockout observable containing `"ABC"`. Then we're creating an instance of that view model and applying it to the page. Now if you make any changes in the input it should update the value of `AppViewModel.firstName`.

Or to keep it more similar to your code you can do it like this:

```
var viewModel = function (){
    this.firstName = ko.observable("ABC");
}

var AppViewModel = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel);
```

Note that there is no need to create the `model` object with the property `firstName`, you can just initialise the `observable` with a `string` and it will pick up any changes made in the `textInput` binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor function `AppViewModel` takes in the *Model* upon construction. The resulting *ViewModel* will be two-way data-bound to the view.

What you'd typically have is a reverse method to the constructor, that can be used e.g. when saving the changes through a *Model* in a back-end. Here's a demo with your example:

```js
function AppViewModel(model){
    var self = this;
    
    self.firstName = ko.observable(model.firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(model.lastName);
    
    self.asModel = ko.computed(function() {
        return {
            firstName: self.firstName(),
            lastName: self.lastName()
        };
    });
    
    self.saveInBackend = function() {
        // Typically you'd ajax here, instead we log the model:
        console.log(self.asModel());
    };
}
var model = {}; 
model.firstName = "John";
model.lastName = "Doe";

var viewModel = new AppViewModel(model);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

Firstname: <input data-bind="textInput: firstName"><br>
Lastname: <input data-bind="textInput: lastName"><br>
<button data-bind="click: saveInBackend">saveInBackend</button>
<h4>Debug info, this is the state of your *view model*:</h4>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
<h4>Debug info, this is the state of an updated model:</h4>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.asModel(), null, 2)"></pre>
<h4>Debug info, this is the state of your *initial model* (which doesn't change):</h4>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(window.model, null, 2)"></pre>
```